# Quartz CronTrigger - Getting next fire time

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm using the Quartz CronTrigger facility to parse cron schedule format strings to determine when a specific job should run.  I'm not actually using Quartz to schedule the job though.

There is a method in CronTrigger called getFireTimeAfter(Date) which gives the next time the job will fire after the given date.  This works well when the supplied date is now or in the future.  But it doesn't seem to work if the date is in the past.

```
Date currTime = new Date();
CronTrigger tr = new CronTrigger();
tr.setCronExpression("0 0 23 3,18 * ? *");
Date nextFireAt = tr.getFireTimeAfter(currTime);
System.out.println("Reference time: " + currTime);
System.out.println("Next fire after reference time: " + nextFireAt);
```

Which is a cron schedule to fire at 23:00 on the 3 and 18 of every month.  So for example, if I did this today (August 11), I see:

```
Reference time: Thu Aug 11 10:04:25 MDT 2011
Next fire after reference time: Thu Aug 18 23:00:00 MDT 2011
```

But if I set the reference date to the past, it gives me the same next fire time.

```
Reference time: Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 MST 1969
Next fire after reference time: Thu Aug 18 23:00:00 MDT 2011
```

I was expecting the output to be:

```
Reference time: Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 MST 1969
Next fire after reference time: Wed Aug 3 23:00:00 MDT 2011
```

Is the method just not intended to work that way or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: @Kal - yes I know.  I am trying to figure out when the trigger would have fired after the given date, even if it is in the past.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What you really want to use the the CronExpression object directly not the CronTrigger.  As you discovered, it won't calculate next run times in the past... but CronExpression will!

CronExpression has the method: getNextValidTimeAfter.  This is what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to find all occurences within a datetime range?

Comment: @ManikArora : You can do a while loop calling getNextValidTimeAfter passing as parameter first the beginning datetime, and then all returned timestamps on each iteration, and you loop while those timestamps are still less than the ending time.
On each iteration you can add the resulting Dates to the list of occurrences.

Answer (score 6):

In Spring you can follow the same approach they use in their integration tests.
[CronTriggerTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/test/java/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTriggerTests.java)

```
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
trigger.setCronExpression("0 0 23 3,18 * ? *");
SimpleTriggerContext triggerContext = new SimpleTriggerContext();
triggerContext.update(null, null, new Date());
Date nextFireAt = trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CronTrigger.getFireTimeAfter()` method has a protection mechanism for preventing the specified after time to be in the past.

This can be circumvented by calling `setStartTime` firth with the time in the past you are evaluating.  Then the call to `getFireTimeAfter` should return with a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Quartz doc](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html#getFireTimeAfter%28Date%29):

> Returns the next time at which the CronTrigger will fire, after the given time

"Will fire" implies "in the future". That is, the next time the `CronTrigger` will fire is not in the past, and dates in the past aren't returned.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to acheieve, but you night be interested in those methods:

- getPreviousFireTime(): Returns the last time the trigger was fired
- getTimeBefore(): Returns the time the trigger fired before a given date (works in the past) -- Note: this one seems to be unimplemented for now

Comment: I'm trying to use the CronTrigger to know if a certain "due date" has happened.  The two pieces of information I have are the "last due date time" and the cron schedule.  So what I want to do is  getFireTimeAfter(lastDueDate) to tell me if whether I am past the current due date.   Looks like getTimeBefore() may be what I'm looking for -- too bad it's not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of weird but the protection mechanism exists. No idea why Quartz Team have that check. The below test passes only if I add an hour to the `nxtDay`
(`nxtDay = nxtTrigger.Value.DateTime.AddHours(1);`)

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");

//FREQUENCY OF SECONDS 
var reccurrence = new Reccurrence
{
    StartTime = new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0),
    StopTime = new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0),
    WeekDay = "MON-SUN",
    TimeZoneInfo = timeZoneInfo,
    Frequency = 15,
    FrequencyUnit = FrequencyUnit.Seconds
};

var autoPublishDetail = new AutoPublishJobDetail("TestReccurence_Seconds", _log, null, reccurrence);
var trigger = autoPublishDetail.GetDailyTrigger();
var nxt = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();

var jobSeconds = JobBuilder.Create().WithIdentity(new JobKey("TestReccurence_Seconds")).OfType(typeof(AutoPublishJob)).Build();

_scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobSeconds, trigger);

//This job sud run 4 times in a 60 secs and from 9 am to 11 am (Span of 3 hrs including 11 onwards to 11:59:59)
//Total runs = 4 x 60 x 3 = 720
var today = DateTime.Now;
var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
DateTime? nxtDay = new DateTime(tomorrow.Year, tomorrow.Month, tomorrow.Day);

int jobCnt = 0;
do
{
    var nxtTrigger = trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(nxtDay.Value);

    if (nxtTrigger.Value.Year.Equals(today.AddDays(2).Year) && nxtTrigger.Value.Month.Equals(today.AddDays(2).Month) && nxtTrigger.Value.Day.Equals(today.AddDays(2).Day))
        break;

    jobCnt++;
    nxtDay = nxtTrigger.Value.DateTime.AddHours(1);

} while (true);

Assert.AreEqual(720, jobCnt);
```